# why does imported python script in a django custom command overrides optparse options

Tags: python, django, command, optparse

I have a custom command in django which calls another script as follows:

```
import script

from optparse import make_option
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option(
            "-f", 
            "--files", 
            dest = "files",
            help = "add files to list",
            action='store_true',
            default=False
        ),

        # Some more options here
    )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        script.main(files=options['files'])
```

My custom script also uses `optparse`. It looks something like this.

```
from optparse import OptionParser

opts = OptionParser()
opts.add_option('-f', '--files', dest='files', action='store_true', default=false, help='file help message')
opts = opts.parse_opts()[0]

FILE = opts.file

def main(files=false):
    opts.files = files
    # Do the processing
```

Now when I try to run the command `python manage.py command --option-other-than-file`, it always prints the help message with only `--help` and `--file` as an option. Also the help message for `--files` option is the one defined in the import script and not in the command file. Also when I try printing the options using `python manage.py command --help` it shows the same message. It seems like some how the options are being overridden. can somebody tell me what's going on. Thanks.

#### Edit

Here is the code to the [`BaseCommand` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/base.py)

Answer (score 1):

When you first `import script` in your command it executes all the code at the top level of `script.py`, including the `opts.parse_opts()` line. I dont think optparse is supposed to allow for two such consecutive calls in a same process.

Just move your `script.py` optparse part in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause so it won't fire when using it as a module and you should be fine.